How To Count Unique Values in a Filtered List in Excel
I have a large table in excel with 20+ headings.
I am filtering the list based on a heading in Column Z.
I want to find the number of unique serial numbers that are defined in Column O.
I filtered the list, but don't know how to count unique serial numbers.

Try: =ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(G2:Z100,(MAP(O2:O100,LAMBDA(α,SUBTOTAL(103,α))))))) . Also try to post what you have tried and sample data as copiable text.

The above.... But then applied to column O :)

@JvdV Sir, thank you fixed it. I missed the column O. Thought its Z
